# Extracting an array from within an object

Tags: arrays, data-extraction, array.prototype.map

I have the following JSON object from which I'd like to extract a specific property

```
{
  "gender": "male",
  "age": 36,
  "profession": "teacher",
  "hobbies": [
    {
      "id": 28,
      "name": "gardening"
    },
    {
      "id": 878,
      "name": "Football"
    },
    {
      "id": 35,
      "name": "Reading"
    },
    {
      "id": 10751,
      "name": "Socialising"
    }
  ],
  "Country": "Sweden",
  "id": 4542236,
}
```

Lets say I wanted to create a new object that hold only the "hobbies" property with all the values like this

```
{  
  "hobbies": [
    {
      "id": 28,
      "name": "gardening"
    },
    {
      "id": 878,
      "name": "Football"
    },
    {
      "id": 35,
      "name": "Reading"
    },
    {
      "id": 10751,
      "name": "Socialising"
    }
  ]
}
```

Since the JSON is coming from an external API I have no control on future positioning (index) of any properties

Comment: Are you working in JS ? If you know the index of the array ("hobbies") then a simple ```var hobbies = yourJSON.hobbies``` otherwise you should use ```Object.keys(yourJSON)``` and check every child value if it's an array with something like ```Array.isArray()```. BTW, I can make a more elaborate answer if you give more informations about your problem

Comment: Yes working on React meaning using JS and I usually use .map to iterate through arrays. I'm not after the index, I just want to extract "hobbies" and use it elsewhere in my code. Thanks

Comment: Did you mention using React in your question ? It looks like ``var hobbies = {};
hobbies["hobbies"] = yourJSON.hobbies``` is enough then... BTW, you shouldn't keep the "hobbies" key in an object containing only hobbies